# How to add a default group to a logged user in dokuwiki?

Tags: php, cas, dokuwiki

I have a CAS DB and installed phpCAS with CAS plugin for my wiki.

I want to add a default group to all logged users through CAS (group: user) for managing the ACL.

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

DokuWiki has a default group. each user that logs in will be assigned to this group.

The option is called [defaultgroup](https://www.dokuwiki.org/config%3adefaultgroup). The default value is *user*. You can also change this.

It seems that in some cases these option isn't set correct In this case just change the */inc/auth/cas.auth.php*. Add the following line after 74:

```
$USERINFO['grps'][] = $conf['defaultgroup'];
```

I added the line on the [CAS page at DokuWiki.org](https://www.dokuwiki.org/auth%3acas?&#files_to_install). If you have no custom changes on the file just download it and replace your version.